# Why can't I get this SQLite code to load the proper data for my detail view?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, sqlite, ios-simulator

```
- (void) hydrateDetailViewData {
//if detail view is hydrated then do not get it from database
if(isDetailViewHydrated) return;

if(detailStmt == nil) {
    const char *sql = "select snapTitle, snapDesc from Snap where snapID =?";
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &detailStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating detail view statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    NSLog(@"SQLite= %d", sqlite3_step(detailStmt)); 

}

if (sqlite3_step(detailStmt) == SQLITE_ROW)//execute sql statement on database, and make sure it executed properly.
{
    self.snapDescription = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(detailStmt, 1)];
}
```

looking at the above code, can someone tell me what's wrong and why is it that i can't get it to load on my detailview?i basically followed the tutorial on iphone sdk article..but yet i am having this don't know why error.

i can even send my project if u guys need to take a look.

Error msg:

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] was unable to load a nib named "DetailView"'
2010-03-15 16:35:55.202 Snap2Play[58213:20b]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error and your problem don't match, the error is nothing to do with the above code as far as I can see.

The error is to do with a call to [loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW15) - I'm guessing that you don't have a xib file in your project called DetailView.xib

Comment: i do have the xib with the correct filename..i need help seriously..i do not know where i had gone wrong..

Comment: What is the stack trace in the debugger when your code crashes? If you put that into your question more people might be able to help?

Comment: Also, if you put a link to the article in the question I can try to reproduce it on my machine and see what might be wrong?

Comment: http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2008/10/sqlite-tutorial-loading-data-as.html i follow the tutorial..but instead of getting int i am getting character instead..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing a statement to bind a parameter to your SQL select statement. You have this:

```
const char *sql = "select snapTitle, snapDesc from Snap where snapID =?";
```

but you never set the value for snapID anywhere that I can see. You need a statement like this before you execute the query:

```
sqlite3_bind_int(detailStmt, 1, snapID);
```